# A problem with "as...as": "Mike has as cute a cat as you do"

Tags: word-order, as

Take the below sentence for example:

> Mike has as **cute a cat** as you do.

I wonder if it's a "cute a cat" or "a cute cat"?

Comment: Or you can say: "Mike's cat is as cute as your cat." Or "Your cat is as cute as **Mike's cat**". But I have a question: Is it correct to say "Your cat is as cute as **Mike's**."?

Answer (score 5):

It's always **"as** *ADJECTIVE* **a**[n] *NOUN* **as"**

As cute a cat as..
As big a job as..
As steep a hill as..
As fierce a dog as..
As wise *an* owl as..

...you've ever seen.

Comment: Or we can also say: "Mike's cat is as cute as your cat." Or "Your cat is as cute as *Mike's cat*." But I have a question: Is it correct to say "Your cat is as cute as *Mike's*."?

Comment: 'Is it correct to say "Your cat is as cute as Mike's."?' - yes.

Comment: You can use "adverb+adjective" or even "verb" after "as" in the same way. "As loving a man as my father" or "As highly probable a chance as this"

Answer (score -2):

It's not a question of "**a cat**" or "**cat a**".
The sentence means that Mike has a cat and it's as cute as the one you have.

So, the correct phrasing would be

> Mike has **as a cute a cat** as you do.

Edit: See Tetsujin's answer for more examples.

Comment: We don't place an article before the adjective in this case.