# as ... as structure is very difficult to understand!

Tags: adjectives, word-order, as

I can't understand **as ... as** structures in English. According to grammar books between the two as we should place an **adjective**, but I have seen several cases which there was something else. For example look at the following sentences and tell me which one is correct?

> 1. I could not live in a city as crowded as Tokyo.
> 2. I could not live in as crowded a city as Tokyo.

I think the first one is correct, but I also saw the second one in a book. If both are correct please let me know if there is any difference or not.

Comment: The second version is a "literary inversion" (changing the order of the words for literary effect). But actually, for some people it's perfectly natural even in conversational contexts.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/178163/9161 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/122562/9161